# How to Read and Parse .xlsx file in Vert.x File System

Tags: java, excel, angular, apache-poi, vert.x

I am working on an application to parse a .xlsx file using an angular front-end and a Vert.x back-end. I have an angular component that posts the file to a URL that the Vert.x back-end handles "/upload" and this works just fine.

However, I need to parse this file within the back-end in Java and I have already written a Parser using Apache POI. I can open the file as an AsyncFile in the Vert.x File System, but I am not sure how to use this AsyncFile object in a way that Apache Poi can understand it (java.io.InputStream, java.io.File, for example).

Is there a way to do this or a functionality in Vert.x I can use to parse the .xlsx file and use it to dynamically populate my angular application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using Apache POI and use Vertx to read the file than you have two options to work with Vert.x's FileSystem API:

**Non Blocking**

```java
vertx.fileSystem().readFile("/path-to-file/foo.xlsx", asyncResult -> {
    if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
        Buffer result = asyncResult.result();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes());
        // use apache poi with the input stream
    } else {
        // handle errors
    }
});
```

**Blocking** (Should be avoided, it can block the event-loop)

```
Buffer result = vertx.fileSystem().readFileBlocking("/path-to-file/foo.xlsx");
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes());
// use apache poi with the input stream
```

Comment: The blocking version should be avoided. It may block the event loop

Comment: @tsegismont you are correct, thanks. Edited my response with a disclaimer.